# Refactor function to search and replace values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, refactoring

I  have following multi dimensional array

```
$results = array(
    'name'     => 'signed_contract_message',
    'required' => ':min',
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim')
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array('name' => ':max'),
        array(
            'name'    => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array(
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'min'      => ':min',
                'max'      => ':max',
                'values' => array(
                    'option_1' => ':min',
                    'option_2' => ':max'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I want to search and replace the occurrences of `:min` and `:max` which is stored in following array

```
$placeHolders = array(':min' => 2, ':max' => 100);
```

I created the following function to do the job

```
function searchAndReplacePlaceHolders($results, $placeHolders)
{
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        if (is_string($result) && array_key_exists($result, $placeHolders)) {
            $results[$key] = $placeHolders[$result];
        }
        if (is_array($result)) {
            foreach ($result as $key1 => $result1) {
                if (is_string($result1) && array_key_exists($result1, $placeHolders)) {
                    $results[$key][$key1] = $placeHolders[$result];
                }
                if (is_array($result1)) {
                    foreach ($result1 as $key2 => $result2) {
                        if (is_string($result2) && array_key_exists($result2, $placeHolders)) {
                            $results[$key][$key1][$key2] = $placeHolders[$result2];
                        }
                        if (is_array($result2)) {
                            foreach ($result2 as $key3 => $result3) {
                                if (is_string($result3) && array_key_exists($result3, $placeHolders)) {
                                    $results[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3] = $placeHolders[$result3];
                                }
                            }
                            if (is_array($result3)) {
                                foreach ($result3 as $key4 => $result4) {
                                    if (is_string($result4) && array_key_exists($result4, $placeHolders)) {
                                        $results[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3][$key4] = $placeHolders[$result4];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

This works, but what i wanted to know is if we can improve this function or perhaps do it in better way ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using `array_walk_recursive` function would be the best solution in such case:

```
array_walk_recursive($results, function(&$v, $k, $ph){
    if (is_string($v) && array_key_exists($v, $ph)) {
            $v = $ph[$v];
    }
}, $placeHolders);
```

---

```
// the final output is shown below:   

 array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(23) "signed_contract_message"
  ["required"]=>
  int(2)
  ["filters"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "StripTags"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "StringTrim"
    }
  }
  ["validators"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      int(100)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "StringLength"
      ["options"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["encoding"]=>
        string(5) "UTF-8"
        ["min"]=>
        int(2)
        ["max"]=>
        int(100)
        ["values"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["option_1"]=>
          int(2)
          ["option_2"]=>
          int(100)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does work, thank you, this is what i was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a recursive functoin which will check if the next element is an array and if so would go one level deeper and if the next element is the wanted one change it with the needed value something like this:

```
function recurseArray(&$array, $val)
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $key=>&$arrayElement)
        {
            if(is_array($arrayElement))
            {
                recurseArray($arrayElement, $val);
            }
            else
            {
                if($arrayElement == $val)
                {
                    //do your magic
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```